# Finding connections in 3 vectors of string

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, stl

I have written in C++ some code, which finds the shortest path between two cities connected by roads or by flights. Cities can be connected with direct flights or indirect ones.
User can type flights like this:

```
AAA AAG 300
AAA AAB 1
AAA AAG 298
AAB AAC 1
AAB AAG 297
AAC AAD 1
AAC AAG 296
AAD AAE 1
AAD AAG 295
AAE AAF 1
AAE AAG 294
AAF AAG 1
```

Where first string is leaving city, second is destination and the number is flight time.
I store these values in 3 vectors:

```
   vector<string> leavingCities;
   vector<string> destCities;
   vector<int> flightTimes;
```

I have trouble with finding indirect flights in these vectors - I mean sometimes direct flight time from AAA to AAG is much bigger than indirect flight through AAB, AAC, AAD, AAE and AAF, and then I have to choose shorter route and store cities which I travelled by.
Is there any solution to find the shortest time and route? The flight list can vary and doesn't have to look like this.
Maybe there's some better container to store data like this?
Please, help me.

Comment: You can model your problem as a `graph` problem and use `shortest path` routing to find the shortest path between two cities.

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm for shortest path algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest route.

Answer (score 4):

You really should split up your question into understanding *how* you're going to solve it and then getting into code. If you don't understand the how you're going to solve it, generally just writing code will not help.

Firstly, your problem can be classified as a Finding the Shortest Path in a Graph algorithm. Wikipedia has a whole page on them but [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) algorithm is probably the best for you.

Once you've understood the how, you can go about implementing it. If you can use them, there are a lot of nice graph libraries out there such as [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html), but I suspect that as an assignment you'll be asked to implement it yourself from scratch. However, I wouldn't recommend looking at the Boost sources as a inexperienced programmer - they're pretty scary, albeit a great way to learn once you've got a bit more experience under your belt.

Good luck